# Android camera photo should not store in device and SD card

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Android application, Using crossplugi,.device info to taking the photo, as per the requirement I need to strore image in DB not in the devices.

```
public async void ExecuteCameraCommand()
{
    int iCount = 0;
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        // await _dialogService.DisplayAlertAsync("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }
    iCount = iCount + 1;

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        SaveToAlbum = false,

    });

    if (file == null)
        return;        
}
```

Comment: save the image to the db and then delete the file.  Also note that CrossMedia has been deprecated in favor of Xamarin Essentials

Answer (score 0):

The file object has a GetStream method. You can use this to get the data and then save it to the database. Something like this:

```
 Stream fileStream = file.GetStream();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
  fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

  //Save to the database
```

I assume you are storing the photos locally on the device in something like a SQLite database. Bear in mind the photos can be several megabytes in size. When I did this I stored the photos on the file system on the device and saved a record in the database of their path and name to avoid bloating the database.

Comment: I am storing in the DB. I am able to delete the Image in Android inside folder. is there any way to avoid string in the device? so that i can remove the delete logic.